# center content on login page

Tags: css

I'm working on a small home project based on PHP and MySQL.  I can do the PHP side of things - with a lot of checking the books :-) - but the HTML side, I don't know that well.  OK, so I learned it back in the 90s and could do frames, forms etc.  But div and class?  Still to learn.  :-|

Anyway, what I want to do is to have the landing page - the index.php therefore, with nothing on it but a logo (say 100px square), and below that, two fields for 'login' and 'password' and below that, a 'submit' and 'reset' button.   All of it centred horizontally and vertically on the page.

I use a default css file, so is it included there, or inline?

Many thanks.

Comment: Both are possible. I do realize there's a lot to learn, but SO is for problems, and you seem to know what you need to learn. So, do it.

Answer (score 0):

Someone asked a similar question before:
[Flexbox: center horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically)

With flexbox vertical and horizontal centering works „out of the box“.
Without it, it is also possible but you need to use some hacks like `display: table-cell` etc. (See https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/ )

So the flexbox solution would be the more clean one!

Comment: Hi.  Yes, I found that question before posting, but my issue is that it doesn't actually say where that text should go.  In a css file?  In my index.php file?

Comment: You can either include your own css file like you include the "default" one `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">` or you could use inline styles on the html elements like `<div style="margin: 0 auto"></div>`. Maybe you should also look for a html and css tutorial to refresh you css skills since this question is fairly common and has been covered in many tutorials on html and css.

Comment: Here is another similar question with a working code snippet to experiment with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div?rq=1

Comment: Here is good answer to your question: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-for-a-beginner-to-learn-HTML-CSS

Answer (score -1):

> I use a default css file, so is it included there, or inline?

In todays standards, you should use the CSS file and include it in your page like so.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">`

It should be placed between the `<head> </head>` tags somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, sloppy language on my part.  The stylesheet is referenced in index.php.  I just wanted to know if the positioning of the elements on the landing page should be in the css file.

Comment: Right. Well, yes, it should be in the file and not inline